# Regex in Hive QL (RLIKE) - performance?

Tags: regex, hiveql

I'm wondering how/if can I improve the regex I'm using in a query. I have a set of identifiers for certain user groups. They can be in two main format:

- `X123` or `XY12`, (type 1)
- any two letter combo, excluding XY (type 2)

Type 1 groups always are of length 4. It's either letter *X* followed by a number between 100 and 999 (inclusive) OR *XY* followed by numbers between 0 and 99 (padded to length 2 with zeros).

Type 2 groups are 2 letter strings, with any letter allowed, excluding XY (although my query doesn't specify this).

User can belong to multiple groups, in which case different groups are separated by pound symbol (`#`). Here's an example:

```
groups     user     age
X124       john     23
XY22#AB    mike     33
AB         peter    21
X122#XY01  francis  43
```

I want to count rows in which at least one group in second format appears, i.e. where user is not exclusively member of groups in first format.

I need to catch all rows (i.e. users) which don't belong exclusively to first type of groups. In the example above, I want to exclude users *john* and *francis* because they are members only of type 1 groups. 
On the other hand, *mike* is OK because he's member of AB group (i.e. group of type 2).

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
select 
  count(*)
from 
  users
where
  groups not rlike '^(X[Y1-9][0-9]{2,2})(#X[Y1-9][0-9]{2,2})*$'
```

Is this bad performance wise? And how should I approach fixing it?

Comment: Your question might do better here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JimSimson I'm cool w/ that - just don't know how/if i can to move it

Comment: I'm not saying, necessarily, that it's wrong here, just might want to post over there as well.

Comment: ok, let's see what happens https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172748/regex-in-hive-ql-rlike-performance :)

Comment: So, for your second group (any two letter combo) can that include XY?

Comment: good question - no, it cannot. this was by design. i'll modify question.

Comment: So, I've tried a few different things, but the best I can come up with is: groups rlike '[A-Z][A-XZ]' which is definitely slower than what you've got. I think you've got the right idea with what you have because you save a whole lot of processing later on with that '^(X' up front. That's my two cents.

Comment: (1) Describe you requested result through you example. Explain why is a specific row qualified / not qualified. (2) be accurate regarding the expected format (lengh,valid characters in each position,number of tokens)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz chill a bit. i explained in a manner that was clear to me. point to a problem if you see one, you don't need to be rude about it. i'm going to edit the description, so thanks for the comment (i guess).

Comment: @hummingBird - :-) Israel http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-6VKl_jw25ac/VmtWZjI9-2I/AAAAAAAABhY/E4G_mpEN0cI/s1600/Cultural%2BGrafica.png

Comment: bosnian serb ;) i guess we're in the same quadrant at least. i wrote my answer for the sake of other readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to count rows in which at least one group in second format appears.

It seems a bit simpler then to select `where groups like`:

```
\b(?:(?!XY)[A-Z]{2})\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary. It doesn't consume a character, instead it states there cannot be a non-alphanumeric character there.

[Live demo.](https://regex101.com/r/EZRsuZ/1)

Comment: you are excluding AY in your example. your  shoudl've caught AY. otherwise, it does look simpler.

Comment: You stated `any two letter combo, as long as second one isn't Y (type 2)`.

I've updated the demo for `group 2 excludes XY`: https://regex101.com/r/EZRsuZ/2

Comment: well, it was an edit .. my bad. i added some edits, but i'll fix group description as well.